# Fail to install brew

Tags: homebrew

When I want to install brew on my mac, the error below appears. May I ask what's wrong with it? I am using Mojave10.14.2.

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

Comment: I'm not a Mac expert but it looks like you're missing dependencies for the installation. Do you have libssl.1.0.0 and libssh2.1 in the location that brew is looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much, Eggplant. I have installed them, and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing libssl.1.0.0.dylib necessary for the installation in your libraries path.